# How to get Data from following type of JSONObject? There is no JSONArray

Tags: android, json

I got below `JSONObject` from `Firebase`.

There is no any `JSONArray` in response.

**How can I get all main `JSONObject` with loop.?**

Is below `JSON` response is valid? or I have to convert into `JSONArray` ?

I know how to get inner `JSONObject` if there is `JSONArray`.

```
{
    "Data": {
        "inner_data": {
            "key1": {
                "chapter": "Chapter 1",
                "key": "key",
                "weight": 1
            },
            "key2": {
                "chapter": "Chapter 2",
                "key": "-KMa5xai7vMQtaDZ0b31",
                "weight": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "Demo": {
        "inner_demo": {
            "key1": {
                "chapter": "Chapter 1",
                "key": "key",
                "weight": 1
            },
            "key2": {
                "chapter": "Chapter 2",
                "key": "-KMa5xai7vMQtaDZ0b31",
                "weight": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "Test": {
        "inner_test1": {
            "-KMa9JFjKuDNgf313Bzc": {
                "key": "-KMa9JFjKuDNgf313Bzc",
                "time": "10:33",
                "topic": "Circles",
                "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLVsv9kO5C8",
                "weight": 1
            }
        },
        "-inner_test2": {
            "-KMa95pUP3bKtnoQaPg4": {
                "key": "-KMa95pUP3bKtnoQaPg4",
                "time": "15:26",
                "topic": "Linear Equations in two Variables",
                "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wpr3tddDw9s",
                "weight": 1
            }
        },
        "-inner_test3": {
            "-KMa8i5mU9HUapf-wGDU": {
                "key": "-KMa8i5mU9HUapf-wGDU",
                "time": "05:38",
                "topic": "Measurement of volumes",
                "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbFwgu4xx40",
                "weight": 1
            }
        },
        "inner_demo_test": {
            "key1": {
                "chapter": "Chapter 1",
                "key": "key",
                "weight": 1
            },
            "key2": {
                "chapter": "Chapter 2",
                "key": "-KMa5xai7vMQtaDZ0b31",
                "weight": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE : This is only 10% of total response.

Comment: Make a Model class and then get the objects and use it as required. For more refer here http://coderzpassion.com/saving-retrieving-data-firebase-android-part-one/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json you provided is valid, If you know the keys you can simply say

```
obj.getJSONObject("key");
```

If you don't know the keys, you can use iterator

```
JSONObject j=new JSONObject();
    Iterator<String> iterator=j.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        String key=iterator.next();
       JSONObject newObj= j.getJSONObject(key);
    }
```

to fetch nested objects.

Comment: Let me try. I'll be back .